# Setup G Suite and Mailgun to receive email

Tags: google-apps, mailgun

I would like to use both G Suite and mailgun to receive email.

For example:

- a@bla.com -> G Suite gmail account
- b@bla.com -> Handled by mailgun, since unknown to G Suite

For this I am pointing MX records of bla.com to G Suite and then routing unknown emails to mailgun using MX from another subdomain mail.bla.com

However I get the following error

```
Google tried to deliver your message, but it was rejected by the server for the recipient domain mail.bla.com by mxb.mailgun.org. [104.130.177.23].

The error that the other server returned was:
550 5.7.1 Relaying denied
```

Answer (score 2):

Trying to do the same thing, I found that relaying for a domain will only be allowed, if it has (additional) MX records pointing to mailgun servers. Once mailgun had verified the MX records, I deleted them and relaying continued to work. However, it is unclear for how long, as mailgun may periodically attempt to re-verify them. Clearly not something suitable for productive use.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely never use multiple MX records on one domain.

You will confuse the servers which finally leads to inconsistency in your email traffic.

According to mailgun `subdomain + MX records` is one possible path to take.

[Further read here ...](https://help.mailgun.com/hc/en-us/articles/203357040-Can-I-Use-the-Same-Domain-Name-for-Mailgun-and-for-Google-Apps-Or-Another-Email-Server-)